# What is this hardened computer called?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

After undergoing a security audit, it was suggested that a hardened computer be placed in the DMZ to run firewall software. What is this hardened computer called?

Comment: Closing as not a real question. Google or Wikipedia would be better for this.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is "perimeter firewall". Have a look on this, to confirm this, as I am not sure about naming.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700828.aspx

[image]